# static files copied, css not being used

Tags: python, css, django, static, django-staticfiles

It's a bit weird how paths look, but it's my first Django app, I'm learning :)

setting.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets', 'C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\UploaderUpdate\Uploader\uploader\static'),
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

main.html (template)

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}">
```

Then in my cmd I do:
`python manage.py collectstatic`
And it says copies files. Now, I have my (I created it) static folder at:

```
C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\UploaderUpdate\Uploader\uploader
```

Unfortunately main app is in folder `main` so it created folder `static` at :

```
C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\UploaderUpdate\Uploader\uploader\uploader\static
```

It contains `assets` and `admin`. But my CSS is not being used, despite my import in the template. Am I linking it wrong?

Comment: Are you using `DEBUG = True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this - link to the CSS needed to be in `{% header %}` part of my template.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(SITE_ROOT,'static'))?
```

I don't know why the absolute path doesn't seem to work. However python manage.py collectstatic should have put all of your static files in the static directory defined by STATIC_ROOT, which uses SITE_ROOT (or BASE_DIR from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/. (I would avoid local absolute paths if you can, for one thing that gives you more work when you go into production.) Also does your SITE_ROOT look like this?

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

I'm 99% sure this gives the absolute path of the directory your settings.py file is in, so if you use this, your static folder should be in the same directory as your settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}">
```

by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css">
```